# Count distinct values in an SQL table for each hour in a day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID    TimeStamp    CarNumber
1    2018\12\03 14:05:32    433
2    2018\12\03 14:13:52    420
3    2018\12\03 14:55:14    433
4    2018\12\03 15:12:03    420
5    2018\12\03 16:15:55    570
```

I have to get the number of distinct car numbers for each hour of the day, so what I do now is run a command for each hour separately:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CarNumber
FROM Cars
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '2018\12\03 14:00:00' AND '2018\12\03 15:00:00'
```

Is there a way to build a table that  will do that for each hour of the day automatically? Expected output:

```
Hour    NumberOfCars    CarNumbers
0       0               0
...
14      2               433, 420
15      1               420
16      1               570
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate by date and hour:

```
select cast(timestamp as date) as thedate,
       datepart(hour, timestamp) as thehour,
       count(distinct CarNumber) as num_cars
from cars
group by cast(timestamp as date), datepart(hour, timestamp)
order by thedate, thehour;
```

You can add a `where` clause if you want the results for only one date.  If you want the results aggregated over multiple days, remove `thedate` from the logic:

```
select datepart(hour, timestamp) as thehour,
       count(distinct CarNumber) as num_cars
from cars
group by datepart(hour, timestamp)
order by thehour;
```

Comment: Can I list the distinct car numbers in another column?

Comment: @user2979612 . . . SQL Server does not have a convenient string aggregation function until much more recently (`string_agg()`).  But you can do so using XML logic.  Google "SQL Server string aggregation" and you'll see examples.

Answer (score 0):

try like below. Extract hours from datetime column and use in group by

```
 select convert(date,TimeStamp),
 DATEPART(HOUR, TimeStamp) ,
 count(distinct CarNumber) numofcars
 from Cars 
 group by convert(date,TimeStamp),DATEPART(HOUR, TimeStamp)
```

Comment: As I asked above, is it possible to list those distinct values? Like in the question or in an alternative way.